# The currentfile is a commonjs module whose imports will produce require

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have written some logic in my app and 20 files and then I want to use a validator and downloaded via yarn this libary

```
yarn add @vinejs/vine
```

Now I want to add it and I got this error :

```
The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls; however, the referenced file is an ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'. Consider writing a dynamic 'import("@vinejs/vine")' call instead.
  To convert this file to an ECMAScript module, change its file extension to '.mts', or add the field `"type": "module"` to 'c:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxx/backend/package.json'.ts(1479)
```

Okey so I typed in package.json type "module" it works but now I have to change on all my folders the extension to .js and if I do it then I got error in my server.ts like this:

```
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\rambo\Desktop\psm-solution\backend\src\server.ts
```

So I removed all my logic and it still exists the error "Must use import to load ES Module". But I use import. What I am doing wrong ?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev ./src/server.ts --watch",
    "start:prod": "yarn run build && node ./dist/src/server.js",
    "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "type": "module",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
....
```

ts.config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "ESNext" /* ESNext includes new Level-4 features that were
               recently added to the ECMA-262 JS spec */
     ],

    "module": "NodeNext",/* (1 of 2) TS v4.7 settings you need 
                            to change */

    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext", /* This is the one that will 
                                    specifically solve the error you're 
                                    getting. Without the internal changes
                                    made by this, your project will not
                                    resolve modules correctly. */

    "esModuleInterop": true, /* This is properly configured. FYI you cannot 
                                change this, it must be set to true. */
                                

    /* 
      THE REST OF THE SETTINGS DO NOT AFFECT THE MODULE TYPE OR HOW TSC 
      RESOLVES OTHER MODULES */
     "allowJs": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "build",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

server.ts

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';
import express from 'express';
import { ProfilingIntegration } from '@sentry/profiling-node';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import { errorHandler } from './middleware/errorHandler.js';
import { rateLimiter } from './rateLimit/rateLimit.js';
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import { Database } from './config/database.types.js';
import { router_auth } from './routes/auth/auth.js';
import { verifyJWT } from './middleware/verifyJWT.js';

const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
 console.log('SERVER LISTEN ON PORT 3000');
});
```

I hope you can help me to solve this issue above where he said "The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls... "